# Deserialize Dynamic JSON Object

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, deserialization

I am using a thirdparty API and the Json response that I receive back is as below.
Usually, using something like

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(response);
```

I can easily create a .Net model. However, I am struggling on how to formulate the below. I've tried KeyValuePairs, strings, modifying the actual Json but cannot seem to get any joy.

What am I missing?

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "qty": 1,
      "discount": "flat",
      "price": 71.68
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "qty": 1,
      "discount": "flat",
      "price": 62.75
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "qty": 1,
      "discount": "flat",
      "price": 77.28
    }
  ],
  "4": [
    {
      "qty": 1,
      "discount": "flat",
      "price": 82.88
    }
  ],
  "5": [
    {
      "qty": 1,
      "discount": "flat",
      "price": 67.84
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, what is throwing me is that the numbers(1,2,3,4,5) are Identifiers so will not stay constant and could change each time you receive the response.

Comment: Try sticking the JSON into this tool to help you build the schema class. https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: How about `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` ? (where MyClass is qty, discount, price) (or maybe Dictionary<string, MyClass[]> because although there is only 1 object per index, it appears to be an array).

Comment: @KieranDevlin It generates rubbish (class1, class2, class3 etc)

Comment: Your going to have to use a [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and/or a custom serialiser for that JSON. I'd suggest your root cause here is whatever is generating that JSON. I'm presuming it's supposed to be an array but it looks like it's parsing the array index as an attribute, fix that not the parsing here

Comment: @Neil, Dictionary is effectively the same as KeyValuePair<string,MyClass> and returns the same error, Problem is, the Identifiers in this format become the property name and not a value

Comment: @Liam, I am not in control of the API, as stated, a thirdparty

Comment: Well you custom serialisation it is then... good luck

Comment: @KieranDevlin, I have used "Paste Json as Classes" within VS, and as Neil stated, it create a rubbish model, where the parameter names are 1,2,3,4,5 which are Lists of the actual Models

Comment: How does `MyModel` look like? It seems, that `Dictionary<string, MyModel[]>` (value should be an array) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Liam's suggestion of JObject I have come up with this working solution

```
public class MyObject
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public string discount { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

and then after retrieving the JSON response...

```
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);

        List<MyObject> myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

        foreach (var item in jsonObj.AsJEnumerable())
        {
                var csp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(item.First.ToString());

                csp.ForEach(a => { a.product_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.Path); });
                    
                myObjects.AddRange(csp);
         }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think Newtonsoft can do this for you.

```
string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

var jsonReturn = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>( json );
Console.WriteLine( jsonReturn.Email );
```

Based on this link:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

This is the most basic explanation. Use a foreach to iterate over de nodes